# java help with weka: UnsupportedAttributeTypeException

Tags: java, exception, machine-learning, weka

So I'm working with the Weka Machine Learning Library in Java...

I was trying to implement this: http://weka.wikispaces.com/Text+categorization+with+Weka

at the bottom you can download TextCategorizationTest.java which does text categorization and the text_example.zip which contains a whole bunch of htmls....

so I tried running TextCategorizationTest using the class1 directory in the text_example as argument....but then I encountered this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" weka.core.UnsupportedAttributeTypeException: weka.classifiers.trees.j48.C45PruneableClassifierTree: Cannot handle multi-valued nominal class!
    at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:936)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1105)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.test(Capabilities.java:1018)
    at weka.core.Capabilities.testWithFail(Capabilities.java:1297)
    at weka.classifiers.trees.j48.C45PruneableClassifierTree.buildClassifier(C45PruneableClassifierTree.java:116)
    at weka.classifiers.trees.J48.buildClassifier(J48.java:236)
    at TextCategorizationTest.main(TextCategorizationTest.java:55)
```

which refers to this line:

```
classifier.buildClassifier(dataFiltered);
```

does anybody what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick look reveals that the classifier that you are using does not supports multi-valued nominal class. Can you try by changing your class to binary ? Or use different classifier that supports multi-valued nominal class (like SMO or NN in weka)?